# aws s3 bucket image upload in angular6 having problem in return

Tags: angular6, aws-sdk

I am using this approach to upload images to aws s3 bucket:
https://grokonez.com/aws/angular-4-amazon-s3-example-how-to-upload-file-to-s3-bucket

This works fine as an individual task but as far as I rely on the result which is coming a bit later due to async behavior may be. I would like the next task to be executed just after the confirmation.

```
upload() {
      let file: any;
      // let urltype = '';
      let filename = '';
      // let b: boolean;
      for (let i = 0 ; i < this.urls.length  ; i++) {
        file = this.selectedFiles[i];
        // urltype = this.urltype[i];
        filename = file.name;
        const k = uuid() + '.' + filename.substr((filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
        this.uploadservice.uploadfile(file, k);
        console.log('done');
        // console.log('file: ' + file + ' : ' + filename);
        // let x = this.userservice.PostImage('test', file);
         // console.log('value of ' + x);
      }
      // return b;
     }
```

fileupload service:

```
bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
        return false;
      }
      console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
      return true;
    }).promise();
  }
```

Here, done is getting executed before the file upload is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check out a tutorial for asynchronous programming and try to play around with couple of examples using simple timeouts to get the hang of it and then proceed with more complex things like s3 and aws.

Here is how I suggest you start your journey:

1) Learn the basic concepts of asynchronous programming using pure JS
https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html

2) Play around with your own examples using callbacks and timeouts

3) Replace the callbacks with Promises

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

4) Do it the "angular" way with rxjs Observables (similar to JS Observable)

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

PS: To be more concrete:

Your code fails because the following line is executed in an asynchronous manner. Thus the code will call your **uploadfile** function and will immedietly continue executing without waiting.

```
this.uploadservice.uploadfile(file, k);
```

Once you follow all the points I described above you will be able to do something like this (using a Promise):

```
this.uploadservice.uploadfile(file, k)
  .then( result => {
     console.log('Upload finished');
   })
  .catch(error => {
     console.log('Something went wrong');
  });
```

Comment: Your answer seems very helpful and I am going to read it now. But as of now, I would need the exact working code. I tried your solution but "then" for void is not valid. I tried to put return in the calling function but that does not help.